# Shift key stuck in steam overlay

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam, mods

I've got more or less the same problem as this guy: https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/224446340336290335/
Just that Sticky keys isn't the solution.

**Summary:**
I couldn't sprint in Skyrim SE (Fixed it, I'll get to that in a moment), no matter what key bindings I used, I believe this was due to the SHIFT key being permanently stuck (Held down).

When I enter the steam overlay using Shift + Tab, unless i press any other buttons first, it automatically types as if shift is held down. I do not mean CAPS LOCK, because numbers and other keys also turn into the symbol you get when pressing SHIFT without me pressing anything else than the number.

I've got around 70 mods activated, the problem begun after I used an animation based mod, and loading a save before the problem started solves it. I managed to solve the sprinting issue by disabling the mods, quicksaving, and enabling them again, but the shift key is still stuck in the steam overlay.

I've never had the problem before the mods caused it, and disabling the mods doesn't seem to fix it.

To conclude: the only remaining problem is the SHIFT key being stuck in the Steam overlay, and sticky keys is disabled and always has been.

Have any of you encountered this problem before? If so, what's the solution?

Comment: This can happen if you alt-tab while in the overlay.